# ¿Como puedo comparar una contraseña encriptada ya guardada en base de datos para que la nueva no sea igual?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security

Estoy tratando de verificar si una clave de usuario se repite

Mi clase WebSecurity:

```
    @Autowired
    private UsuarioRepositoryImpl usuarioRepositoryImpl;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(usuarioRepositoryImpl).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
```

Controlador:

```
@Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<String> crear(@Valid @RequestBody Usuario usuario) {
        try{  
            String pass = usuario.getPass();
            //ENCRIPTO LA CONTRASEÑA
            String encodedPassword = passwordEncoder.encode(pass);

            Usuario new_us = new Usuario(usuario.getCorreo(), encodedPassword);

            return new ResponseEntity<String>("Usuario creado con exito..", HttpStatus.OK);
        }catch (Exception e){
            System.out.println(e);
            return new ResponseEntity<String>("Ha ocurrido un Error..\n"+e, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
        }
    }
```

Esto funciona perfecto, se guarda el correo y la clave encriptada. El problema se presenta cuando quiero consultar esa clave, ya que al momento de cambiarla debo asegurarme de que no sea igual a la anterior

He intentado esto:

```
@PostMapping("v1/usuario/correoypass") 
    public Boolean obtenerUsuarioPorCorreoYPass(@RequestBody Usuario usuarioBuscado){
        String correo = usuarioBuscado.getCorreo();
        String pass = usuarioBuscado.getPass();

        Usuario usuario = usuarioRepository.findByPassAndCorreo(pass,correo);


        if(usuario!=null){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }
```

He tratado de comparar las claves cifrando la clave entrante y sin cifrar.. pero en ambos casos obtengo el mismo resultado "false"

Mi duda es en si ¿como puedo consultar o comparar las claves encriptadas?

Quiero agregar que llevo muy poco tiempo trabajado con java y spring boot

Comment: Si comparas los 2 valores cifrados, deberían ser diferentes si el valor cifrado también lo es.

Comment: También he intentado comparar el valor entrante sin cifrar y obtengo el mismo resultado

Comment: Assegurate que la nueva la cifras usando el mismo método que el anterior.

Comment: De hecho así esta.. estoy cifrando con el mismo método

Answer (score 0):

```
yo lo haria a si
La clase repositorio
@Repository
public interface EjemploRepository extends JpaRepository<Ejemplo, Long> {
    boolean existsByPassword(String password);  //buscando el password bd

}
despues me iria para el servicio 
@Autowired
EjemploRepository ejemploRepository 


public boolean existeByPassword(String password){
return ejemploRepository.existsByPassword(password); 
}

Controllador ya verifico
@Autowired
EjemploService ejemploService;

@PostMapping("/registrar")
    public ResponseEntity<?> nuevo(@Valid @RequestBody EjemploUsuario ejemploUsuario{
    
  if(ejemploService.existsByPassword(ejemploUsuario.getPassword)){
 return new ResponseEntity(new Mensaje("password ya existe"), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
}
```

Comment: Por favor considera explicar lo que hace tu código con un poco más de detalle. Sería recomendable que leas [answer] y también que hagas el [tour] para ganar tu primera medalla. BIinvenido a [es.so].

Comment: Sin una explicación de como funciona, es como un misterio sin desentrañar.